# Change loader in Vuejs Component

Tags: vue.js

I'm using this loader screen with vuejs **as component**, and i would like to put my own spinner.

I have tried to change it from source code but nothing happened. Anyone can help ?

Thank you.

This is the link :
[vue-loading-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-loading-overlay)

What  tried :

In : `node_modules\vue-loading-overlay\src\loaders\dots.vue`

```
<template>
  <a><img src="spinner.png"></a>
</template>
```

But still dots show up instead of my **spinner.png**.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried?

Comment: Hello sir, yes, i updated post for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **SHOULD NEVER** modify `node_modules`, because subsequent instals will erase your edits. I have found from the docs that this component accepts loader icon through default slot. [Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-loading-overlay#available-slots).

> `default` : Replace the animated icon with yours

So just pass your image through default slot in your `template`.

```html
<loading><img src="spinner.png"></loading>
```

**Notice**: provide valid path to your image.